# Can I Use 'forChild' of Formly Within a Component Improts to Centralize Dependencies?

Tags: angular

Prior to Angular standalone, I utilized the `forChild` function of [Formly](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/main/src/core/src/lib/core.module.ts) to define types for specific ngModules.

Now, with standalone components, I've discovered that I can achieve the same using the router by employing `forChild` there.

However, I'm curious if it's feasible to utilize `forChild` within the component itself. My aim is to consolidate all component dependencies within the imports/providers, rather than dispersing them elsewhere like in the router.